# Cross-origin redirect with XHR

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, redirect, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I try to realize the following scenario:

- load a page from origin A.com
- start a synchronous XHR request from a script on that page to a resource on the same origin A.com
- this request is then answered with a 302-redirect to a resource on another origin B.com

I would expect that this cross-origin redirect is processed, but instead an error is returned by the XHR-send method and no request nor preflight request is triggered.

- Chrome (26): error message 'NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101'
- Firefox (20): error message [Exception... "Failure" nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)" ...
- IE9: no error message but XHR send() returns with status=12017

According to the [XHR specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#infrastructure-for-the-send%28%29-method) I would have expected that the redirect also works cross-origin.

Any idea how to get this cross-origin redirect running?

Answer (score 2):

That won't work because the redirect is handled by the browser and the XHR only sees the page the browser got redirected to—which means it **is** cross domain—which means that it will fail unless B.com explicitly allows your A.com domain to access it.

You can also have your other page on A.com to act as a proxy and download the content on B.com itself and then output the response it got back.

Comment: When calling the resource on B.com directly with XHR (i.e. without redirect) a request is sent to B.com which enables B.com to allow access to the response using CORS header. But this request (or at least a preflight request) is not done when having a redirection. So B.com has no chance to explicitly allow domain A.com to access whatever B.com would respond.